# Can't migrate after installation of django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm following the docs of [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) for installation, but I'm unable to `manage.py migrate`. I've included `'django.contrib.sites'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, and `SITE_ID = 1`, but I get the error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" already exists
```

I'm running Django 2.1.5.

I can't find anything about `"django_site" already exists`, only `"django_site" does not exist`.

What I have in installed apps, excluding internal apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'authtools',
    'lot',
    'bootstrap4',
    'storages',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'bootstrap_pagination',
    'dal',
    'cloudinary',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_filters',
    'reversion',
    'constance',
    'constance.backends.database',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_gravatar',
    'messages_extends',
    'cq',
    'futon',
    'memoize',
    'jam',
    'drf_aggregates',
    'batch_requests',
    'webpack_loader',
    'django_prometheus',

    # Core
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Channels
    'channels',
    'channels_redis',

    # allauth
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)
```

Comment: can you post your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS. normally it does not give error when you run manage.py migrate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had previously had `django.contrib.sites` as an `INSTALLED_APP` before, so the migration failed. Fix was just to run `./manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python manage.py migrate sites
python manage.py migrate
```

In INSTALLED_APPS keep `'django.contrib.sites'` at top.