# relation "account_emailaddress" does not exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, google-signin, django-allauth

I am trying to make a Google Sign In for my app but when I try to migrate it gives me the error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "account_emailaddress" does not exist

Here is My Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'videos',
    'embed_video',
    'users',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google', 

]`
```

```
`SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        "SCOPE":[
            'profile',
            'email'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}
    }
}`
```

```
`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # Required by allauth template tags
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                # allauth specific context processors
                "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
                "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",

            ],
        },
    },
]`
```

```
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'
)`
```

```
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

I saw this and tried doing this :

I figured out what the problem was. the allauth uses account app which doesn't support migrations as yet. Initially I had run

python manage.py migrate allauth.socialaccount
python manage.py migrate allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook
Along with this we need to run the syncdb to complete the puzzle.

But it did not work and it gave me another error.
CommandError: No installed app with label 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google'. Did you mean 'google'?
this error so when I do that it gives another one.
CommandError: App 'google' does not have migrations.

So Guys If you faced this before I wait your response It is really important for my Internship
Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568258/cant-migrate-after-installation-of-django-allauth) might help you

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: I have done all the project from the beginning it is working now I think there was DB crash 
Anyways now I have different error :)

Comment: FieldDoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/
UserData has no field named 'username'

do you know what can I do ?

Comment: are you using custom user model?